# How to alert in sales_order_save_after observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am triggering `sales_order_save_after` event after order status has been completed.

```
public function execute(Observer $observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $checkoutSession=$objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
    $status = $checkoutSession->getLastOrderStatus();
    if( $status == "complete")
    { 
        echo "<script>javascript: alert ("message") </script>";
    }
}
```

and my `event.xml` file in `Vendor/Namespace/etc/adminhtml/event.xml`

I just want to show this popup when the order is completed in the admin panel of Magento 2 can anyone help to solve it. and how can I get to know my event is triggered or not.

Comment: Why you want to use alert instead of message manager ? I think it's best practise to use message manager.

Comment: how to do that ? if you have any link can you just share? and i just want to confirm whether i am in the right path ! am i triggering the correct event?

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Is it working for you or not?

Comment: no Its not working!!! @rohan Hapani

Comment: Any error or log?

Comment: Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.   i got this message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86706/discussion-between-ashwini-murthy-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: I tested and now it's working fine.

Comment: please accept answer :) So, It will helpful for other developers :)

Comment: magento 2 order status change event & sales_order_save_after observer https://community.magento.com/t5/Welcome-to-the-Magento-Community/magento-2-order-status-change-event-amp-sales-order-save-after/m-p/141522/highlight/true#M6425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this below code in your observer :

```
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class OrderStatusChange implements ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;
    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        ...
    ) {
        ... 
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        ...
    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

        if($order->getState() == "complete")
        { 
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Order status change successfully')); // You can set your success message here
            $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), $this->redirect->getRefererUrl()); // You can set here on which path you want to redirect
        }
    }
}
```

**Remove generated folder and flush cache**